# sqldatareader error while reading

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, datagridview, sqldatareader

I am extracting the data from mssql server using an sql datareader .. and i want the values within the datareader to be displayed in a datagridview. 
how do i check if a particular field is null ??

Row1["EmployeeID"] = x.GetString(2);
when i use this to extract data from sqldatareader (x) it says 'DATA is null.this method or property cannot be used/!!!'
what else can i use then so as to read even null values.

Comment: Any reason why you are using a dataReader and not something like a DataAdapter which will bring back a dataset and do all the casting for you?

Comment: no such reasons. will it be easier? will it be able to handle null values as well?

Comment: Will give you a quick example below to bind via DataAdapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
Row1["EmployeeID"] = (x.GetValue(2) as string);
```

If you use Getstring it will always throw exception if the value is not a string. If you use GetValue it will return the object and if it's null it will return a [DBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx) Object.

Edit: Use DataAdapter:

```
DataSet ds;
using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
     sqlCon.Open();
     SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand("Select * From Table",sqlCon);
     SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCom);
     sqlDa.Fill(ds);
}
```

You can then bind the ds to your DataGridView.DataSource.

Comment: Can i use a datatable instead of a dataset.?? what difference will it make?

Answer (score 0):

I would code it more like this:

```
Row1["EmployeeID"] =  x[2] == DbNull ? string.Empty : x.GetString(2);
```

Comment: yeah, makes sense, didn't think at makes that much of a difference though and this way you keep your null value, but your's is better :-)